# Javascript validate filename before upload 2

Tags: javascript

Hello Friends i Want to validate upload file option for a specify filename.forexample if my file name is test.docx then user have to uplaod only test.docx from file upload option if user upload another file with different name then it will display popup error "FileName is worng"

Comment: Match `<input type="file">` value with your pattern. It is a pretty basic task. Show some code and effort - then the community will help you.

Comment: You need to add what you have attempted already and any related code, we will not write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some javascript code.

```
$('input#file-input').on('change', function () {
    var file = $(this).val();
    if (!endsWith(file, ".docx")) {
        alert("Invalid file");
    }
});
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y4ebE/

But remember, never trust user input. editing the script or using a cmd such as `curl` make possible to upload another file. Do backend validation!

Comment: i see this http://jsfiddle.net/y4ebE/ url i excatly want this but its not working in my project what i do

Comment: @user3556374 have you added jquery ?  Did you add the id `file-input` to the input file ?

Comment: Please add what you've done. Also, how is the javascript block wrapped in your code ? Directly in a `<script>` tag or in an `onLoad` function? that should be the second one.

Comment: which jquery i used can you send me the link so i can download the jquery

Comment: Include it like that `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` BUT PLEASE POST YOUR PAGE CODE

Answer (score 0):

```
     // jQuery 
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type='file']").bind('change', function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                    // check you file name or type here
                    var name = this.files[i].name;
                    var size = this.files[i].size;
                    var type = this.files[i].type;
                    var lastModified = this.files[i].lastModifiedDate;
                }
      });

// html
<input type="file" name="file" />
```